# What might be the reason for a NullPointerException in SpellChecker.parse?

Tags: android, crash

I'm getting a Null Pointer Exception from SpellChecker.parse. I cannot find any references to SpellChecker in my code base so I'm not sure why I'm experiencing this crash. Does anyone know of a fix for this crash?

Here's the crash:

```
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.text.method.WordIterator.setCharSequence(
    java.lang.CharSequence, int, int)' on a null object reference

    android.widget.SpellChecker$SpellParser.parse + 560 (SpellChecker.java:560)

    android.widget.SpellChecker$SpellParser.parse + 517 (SpellChecker.java:517)

    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 810 (ZygoteInit.java:810)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android, but I assume there is a dependencies file that includes the libraries you specifically want in this project. There may even be a lock file that contains the actual libraries included plus all of their downstream dependencies. If you can add either of those to the question, that might help track down why this library was included.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? This is happening on some devices with Gboard and I can't find a good fix for the issue

Comment: I never found a fix, but the crash seemed to stop happening for me. No reports of it in the last 90 days